# Sharepoint 2013 Multiple listviews in a page using Tabs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view-web-part

[image: ListView Webpart showing 'My Goals' list]

Hi Folks,

Please refer the Image. There are two views available for this list. (All Tasks and Active)

I've displayed this list in a page(sitepages\sample.aspx) using listview webpart. I'm able to associate only one view either 'All Tasks' or 'Active'.

By Default, When I select 'All Tasks'(check attached img) it will take me to 'Lists\AllItems.aspx' page Or If 'All Tasks' view is the current view then when I select 'Active' it takes me to 'Lists\Active.aspx'. I don't want this to happen.

What I want to do is, When I select 'All Tasks' it should display all the tasks/items in the same listview webpart (or) on the same page(sitepages\sample.aspx). Also, when I select 'Active' view it should display contents in the same listview webpart (or) on same page(sitepages\sample.aspx).

FYI: This sample.aspx will have multiple lists on it.

Please let me know about the possibilities on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a workaround for this..

Many Thanks to Ashok Raja for his [post](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Combining-Multiple-Web-Parts-in-SharePoint-2013-to-create-a-Tab-Pages-WebPart.aspx)..

[image: ActiveView]

[image: All Tasks]

I've Added 'All Tasks' and 'Active' views of a list into a tab as followed from the above post.

This is really a good stuff :)

Thanks